# Sed command in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

How do I extract URL's from a file?
My file name is `URL_name.txt`
This file has a lot of url inside.
It looks like this:

```
<pre>
<pre><div></pre><something>something here<href="http://www.google.com/">something here</font>
<font><href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">something</td>

..
..
..
</pre>
```

Here is my idea, I want to remove everything before URLs
then I can remove everything after URL.
How do I use sed command deal with it?
The output should be

```
http://www.google.com/
```

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

Comment: try: `cat URL_name.txt | sed -ne 's/.*\(http[^"]*\).*/\1/p'`

Comment: @Noproblem, No need to use `cat`. `sed` can read input from file. `sed -ne 's/.*\(http[^"]*\).*/\1/p' file`

Comment: @sat thanks, i think correct way to add redirection like this `sed -ne 's/.*\(http[^"]*\).*/\1/p' < file`  ?

Comment: That's some pretty broken HTML you've got there...still, I think that a parser would be able to pick up the strange `<href>` tags (are you sure that these aren't `<a>` tags with an `href` attribute?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep -o 'http://[^"]*' yourfile
```

Answer (score 2):

With `tr` and `grep`:

```
tr '"' '\n' < URL_name.txt | grep http
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using java. as well as you can also try below commands:

1. `egrep -ie "<*HREF=(.*?)>" index.html | cut -d "\"" -f 2 | grep ://`
2. `egrep -ie "<*HREF=(.*?)>" index.html | awk -F\" '{print $2}' | grep ://`